# Rails: STI best way to deal with entity subtypes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an entity `Order` that consists of two sub entities `SalesOrder` and `PurchaseOrder`. These two sub entities share 95% of their behaviour.

Is single table inheritance and the code below the way to best approach this or is there a better way?

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order_type
end

class SalesOrder < Order       
  before_validation(on: :create) do
    self.order_type = OrderType.find_by!(name: "Sales order")
  end
  validates_inclusion_of :order_type_id, in: [OrderType.find_by!(name: 'Sales order').id]  

  validate :potential_savings, numericality: true, allow_nil: true

  default_scope { joins(:order_type).where("order_types.name = ?", "Sales order") }

  # OrderItem also has two sub entities (SalesOrderItem and PurchaseOrderItem with slightly different behaviour)
  has_many :order_items, class_name: "SalesOrderItem", foreign_key: "order_id", inverse_of: :order  
end

class PurchaseOrder < Order       
  before_validation(on: :create) do
    self.order_type = OrderType.find_by!(name: "Purchase order")
  end
  validates_inclusion_of :order_type_id, :in => [OrderType.find_by!(name: 'Purchase order').id]  

  validates_inclusion_of :potential_savings, :in => [nil], allow_nil: true # throw error if not nil

  default_scope { joins(:order_type).where("order_types.name = ?", "Purchase order") }

  # OrderItem also has two sub entities (SalesOrderItem and PurchaseOrderItem with slightly different behaviour)
  has_many :order_items, class_name: "PurchaseOrderItem", foreign_key: "order_id", inverse_of: :order
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know all the details of your data model, but perhaps you can put the shared functionality into a [`Concern`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html) .

Something like:

```
module Orderable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    cattr_reader :order_type

    # All common/shared relations and validations are defined here
    belongs_to :order_type

    before_validation(on: :create) do
      self.order_type = OrderType.find_by!(name: @@order_type)
    end

    validates_inclusion_of :order_type_id, in: [OrderType.find_by!(name: @@order_type).id] 

    default_scope { joins(:order_type).where("order_types.name = ?", @@order_type) }
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def set_order_type(order_type)
      self.class_variable_set("@@order_type", order_type)
    end
  end
end

class SalesOrder < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include the concern and call a method on the concern to set the order_type
  include Orderable
  set_order_type 'Sales order'

  # This validation is too different from the corresponding PurchaseOrder validation
  # so it is put in the model and not in the Orderable concern
  validate :potential_savings, numericality: true, allow_nil: true
end

class PurchaseOrder < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Orderable
  set_order_type 'Purchase order'

  # This validation is too different from the corresponding PurchaseOrder validation
  # so it is put in the model and not in the Orderable concern
  validates_inclusion_of :potential_savings, :in => [nil], allow_nil: true # throw error if not nil
end
```

Not sure if this is more powerful or DRY then going the STI way. Also, the last validation is not implemented yet due to the different formatting of the order_type name, but that can be fixed.

I hope this will help or give some inspiration.

Comment: Nice alternative. Does this approach require two separate tables in the database (PurchaseOrder and SalesOrder)?

Comment: That depends. If the two tables are completely identical, you could use [`table_name`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods.html#method-i-table_name) to manally set the table name for both models and let them point to a shared `orders` table. If there are a lot of different fields in both models/tables, then it is best to create two tables in your database.

Comment: Both André Barbosa's and zwippie's answer are correct and show a different approach. I marked zwippie's as correct simply because it shows how the code in the question can be DRYed up.

Answer (score 1):

A SalesOrder **is an** Order. So, I think inheritance is the best approach. STI is the best strategy if both types have the same or almost the same data. If you feel like this approach will create a lot of empty columns, I would advise to try a different strategy, but keep the inheritance.

Comment: Both André Barbosa's and zwippie's answer are correct and show a different approach. I marked zwippie's as correct simply because it shows how the code in the question can be DRYed up.